# Viewport-style outline shader

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

[image]I'm trying to get a shader that behaves much like the orange outline in the viewport: a flat 2 dimensional outline around the bounds of a mesh that changes with camera angle. The Workbench render engine actually has an option to render those outlines and give them a color. But i need that in eevee and if possible more customizable than just color adjustment.

There's a lot of tutorials on doing toon-like outline but that's not what im looking for as it is 3dimensional.

Does anyone know how to do that?

edit: added picture for further visualisation

Comment: Hello :). What's the difference between a 3D and 2D outline? Perhaps add some images to illustrate what you *don't want* :).

Comment: thanks! i updated the initial post so i hope it is more clear now